# MYSQL PHP - count 25 rows in a table with condition and return only the date value of the 25th row that met the condition

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the JP_n & date of a specific record from a table with say 100 records, after a condition is met.

SELECT Jp_n, Date FROM(SELECT Jp_n, Date, RW FROM FF_LOG WHERE USER_id = 1 and RW >= 2 and incompl = 1 ORDER BY Jp_n limit 5) AS DATE

This will list the first 5 records found which met the conditions.

Jp_n  :  Date

1   :    1985-04-17

2   :    1985-04-18

3    :   1985-04-19

4    :   1985-04-20

5   :    1985-04-20

But all I want is the return values of the last record which met the condition.

5    :   1985-04-20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the 5th matching row. Use `ROW_NUMBER` to number the matching rows. Then only keep the 5th one.

```
SELECT jp_n, date, rw
FROM
(
  SELECT jp_n, date, rw, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY jp_n) AS rn
  FROM ff_log
  WHERE user_id = 1
  AND rw >= 2
  AND incompl = 1
) numbered
WHERE rn = 5;
```

Or use the `LIMIT` clause with an offset:

```
SELECT jp_n, date, rw
FROM ff_log
WHERE user_id = 1
AND rw >= 2
AND incompl = 1
ORDER BY jp_n
LIMIT 4, 1;
```

Comment: Note: ROW_NUMBER() OVER requires Mysql ver. 8 or newer.

Comment: Yes, but the latest pre-8 version 5.7 was released more than eight years ago and is no longer supported.